# CANNOT Map different action and controller in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have created a simple User Module with 3 views (index, login, register).
I am trying to map them to the IndexController in User module which has following code.
The code is running without any error, BUT IS NOT DISPLAYING THE TEMPLATES

Controller code in : User\src\users\Controllers\IndexController

```
namespace Users\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Helper\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public  function indexAction()
    {
        $view = new ViewModel();
        return  $view;
    }

    public function registerAction()
    {
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setTemplate('users/index/new-user.phtml');
        return $view;
    }

    public function loginAction()
    {
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setTemplate('users/index/login');
        return $view;
    }
}
```

And the templates in View are

User\view\index\index.phtml

```
    <h1>Welcome to Users Module</h1>
    <a href="/users/index/login">Login</a>
    <br> <br>
    <a href="/users/index/register">New User Registration</a>
```

User\view\index\login.phtml

```
    <h2> Login </h2>
    <p> This page will hold the content for the login form </p>
    <a href="/users"><< Back to Home</a>
```

User\view\index\new-user.phtml

```
    <h2> New User Registration </h2>
    <p> This page will hold the content for the registration form </p>
    <a href="/users"><< Back to Home</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a template map such as this.

```
// Generated by ZF2's ./bin/templatemap_generator.php
return [
    'application/contact/index'       => __DIR__ . '/view/application/contact/index.phtml',
    'application/index/index'         => __DIR__ . '/view/application/index/index.phtml',
    'application/login/index'         => __DIR__ . '/view/application/login/index.phtml',
    'application/login/newpassword'   => __DIR__ . '/view/application/login/newpassword.phtml',
    'application/login/resetpassword' => __DIR__ . '/view/application/login/resetpassword.phtml',
    'application/menu/post'           => __DIR__ . '/view/application/menu/post.phtml',
    'application/news/index'          => __DIR__ . '/view/application/news/index.phtml',
    'application/news/post'           => __DIR__ . '/view/application/news/post.phtml',
    'application/pagination'          => __DIR__ . '/view/application/pagination.phtml',
    'application/registration/index'  => __DIR__ . '/view/application/registration/index.phtml',
    'error/index'                     => __DIR__ . '/view/error/index.phtml',
    'layout/layout'                   => __DIR__ . '/view/layout/layout.phtml',
];
```

You can generate one by running this command `php ../../vendor/bin/templatemap_generator.php` from your `module/Users` folder. After that in your `module.config.php` file inside `view_manager` array put this
`'template_map' => include __DIR__ . '/../template_map.php',`